# Use Summernote with Vue-components changing their positions

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, summernote

I have a list of Vue-components created with v-for.

Each component includes a textarea for summernote, which works fine.
Each editor loads its text, and the data gets updated when edited.

But when the components position-properties change, the editor-components behave weird.

Sometimes they change, sometimes they dont change position and sometimes they overwrite each other leaving the same string in both editors.

How to bind the component, its textarea-element and the editor instance correctly?

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in orderedItems" class="">
  <component :is="item-text" :key="item.pos" :item="item" :key="item.id"></component>
</div>

<template id="item-text">
  <div class="item-text">
      <textarea class="text-editor" :id="'text-editor-'+item.id" :data-id="item.id" name=""></textarea>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
Vue.component('item-text', {
  props:['item'],
  data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted:function(){
    $('.text-editor[data-id='+this.item.id+']').summernote({    });
    $('.text-editor[data-id='+this.item.id+']').summernote('code', this.item.contents.html);
    var parent = this;
    $('.text-editor[data-id='+this.item.id+']').on('summernote.change', function(we, contents, $editable) {
      var id = we.target.id;
      parent.item.contents.html=contents;
    });
  },
  template: '#item-text'
});
</script>
```

Comment: My solution now is to make the texts editable on click and destroy them before changing positions etc, but i don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is put Summernote into it's own component. Then v-for create multiple components and pass in the v-model as a prop. Trying to load summernote individually straight from the mounted function is going to be confusing and prone to have errors initializing.